# SaveInstanceState on ListView objects

Tags: android, json, listview, bundle, instance

I have an activity that perform a search of movies and parse the JSON results into "Movie" Objects.
after the parsing the Movie objects are being inserted into a ListView Adapter.
When i change oriantation the activity restarts and the results are gone.

How can i prevent this from happen or save the Objects and restore them onRestoreInstanceState?

I have already tried onConfigurationChanged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a little bit of refactoring.

First implement onSaveInstanceState and save your list to a bundle

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState (Bundle outState){
  outState.putSerializable("mylist", mylist);
}
```

Then on your OnCreate check if your bundle has the list and opulate your listview without fetching again your list

```
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if(savedInstanceState!=null && savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist")!=null){
      populateListView(savedInstanceState.getSerializable("mylist"));
  }else{
      fetchList();
  }
}
```